# Mapbox iOS: leaves of cluster crashing sometimes

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-ios

I have a cluster that has a lot of features in it. I have a logic that zooms in on the clusters until a certain zoomlevel. After that i want to get all the features inside this cluster. Most of the time i works correctly using

```
source.leaves(of: cluster)
```

But sometimes it crashes with the error:
**error: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal c++ exception breakpoint(-4)..**

I also tried to first get all children cluster, but somehow the children is always the same cluster, but with a different id:

```
po cluster
<MGLPointFeatureCluster: 0x280f03740; identifier = "112", coordinate = 47.582946, 12.168623, attributes = {
    "5020_only" = 0;
    cluster = 1;
    "cluster_id" = 112;
    "point_count" = 3;
    "point_count_abbreviated" = 3;
}>

(lldb) po source.children(of: cluster)
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <MGLPointFeatureCluster: 0x280f22740; identifier = "113", coordinate = 47.582946, 12.168623, attributes = {
    "5020_only" = 0;
    cluster = 1;
    "cluster_id" = 113;
    "point_count" = 3;
    "point_count_abbreviated" = 3;
}>

(lldb) po source.children(of: source.children(of: cluster).first as! MGLPointFeatureCluster)
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <MGLPointFeatureCluster: 0x280f00700; identifier = "114", coordinate = 47.582946, 12.168623, attributes = {
    "5020_only" = 0;
    cluster = 1;
    "cluster_id" = 114;
    "point_count" = 3;
    "point_count_abbreviated" = 3;
}>

(lldb) po source.children(of: source.children(of: source.children(of: cluster).first as! MGLPointFeatureCluster).first as! MGLPointFeatureCluster)
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <MGLPointFeatureCluster: 0x280f268c0; identifier = "115", coordinate = 47.582946, 12.168623, attributes = {
    "5020_only" = 0;
    cluster = 1;
    "cluster_id" = 115;
    "point_count" = 3;
    "point_count_abbreviated" = 3;
}>

(lldb) po source.children(of: source.children(of: source.children(of: source.children(of: cluster).first as! MGLPointFeatureCluster).first as! MGLPointFeatureCluster).first as! MGLPointFeatureCluster)
▿ 1 element
  - 0 : <MGLPointFeatureCluster: 0x280f0fc80; identifier = "116", coordinate = 47.582946, 12.168623, attributes = {
    "5020_only" = 0;
    cluster = 1;
    "cluster_id" = 116;
    "point_count" = 3;
    "point_count_abbreviated" = 3;
}>
```

And if i try to get the leaves of on of those childs (doesn't matter which one) i always get the error (crash).

Here is my cluster creation:

```
func addCluster(features _features: [MGLPointFeature]?) {
        guard let features = _features else {
            // No features
            return
        }
        
        guard let style = self.style else {
            // No style
            return
        }
        
        // Remove old style
        let all: [CyclingType] = [.bike, .raceBike, .mountainBike, .singleTrail]
        for type in all {
            // Remove old layer
            if let old = style.layer(withIdentifier: Constants.cluster_layer_unclustered + "_\(type.rawValue)") {
                style.removeLayer(old)
            }
        }
        
        if let old = style.layer(withIdentifier: Constants.cluster_layer_clustered) {
            style.removeLayer(old)
        }
        if let old = style.layer(withIdentifier: Constants.cluster_layer_clustered_number) {
            style.removeLayer(old)
        }

        //Remove old source
        if let old = style.source(withIdentifier: Constants.cluster_source) {
            style.removeSource(old)
        }

        // Add new source & style
        let source = MGLShapeSource(identifier: Constants.cluster_source,
                                    features: features,
                                    options: [.clustered: true,
                                              .clusterRadius: 50,
                                              .maximumZoomLevelForClustering: Constants.cluster_max_zoom,
                                              .clusterProperties: ["5019_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5019]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")],
                                                                   "5020_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5020]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")],
                                                                   "5021_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5021]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")],
                                                                   "5022_only": [NSExpression(mglJSONObject: ["all", ["==", ["get", "category"], 5022]]),
                                                                                 NSExpression(forConstantValue: "unknown")]]])
        style.addSource(source)
        
        // Set iamges
        if let icon = UIImage(fromResource: "icon_map_pin_start_travel") {
            style.setImage(icon, forName: "icon_5019")
        }
        if let icon = UIImage(fromResource: "icon_map_pin_start_mountain") {
            style.setImage(icon, forName: "icon_5020")
        }
        if let icon = UIImage(fromResource: "icon_map_pin_start_singletrail") {
            style.setImage(icon, forName: "icon_5021")
        }
        if let icon = UIImage(fromResource: "icon_map_pin_start_race") {
            style.setImage(icon, forName: "icon_5022")
        }
        
        // Show unclustered features as icons. The `cluster` attribute is built into clustering-enabled
        // source features.
        if let types = UAIDManager.cyclingTypes() {
            for type in types {
                // Add new layer
                let ports = MGLSymbolStyleLayer(identifier: Constants.cluster_layer_unclustered + "_\(type.rawValue)", source: source)
                ports.iconImageName = NSExpression(forConstantValue: "icon_\(type.rawValue)")
                let predicate1 = NSPredicate(format: "cluster != YES")
                let predicate2 = NSPredicate(format: "category == \(type.rawValue)")
                ports.predicate = NSCompoundPredicate(andPredicateWithSubpredicates: [predicate1, predicate2])
                ports.iconAllowsOverlap = NSExpression(forConstantValue: true)
                style.insertLayer(ports, at: self.biggestPossibleLayerIndex)
            }
        }

        // Show clustered features as circles. The `point_count` attribute is built into
        // clustering-enabled source features.
        let circlesLayer = MGLCircleStyleLayer(identifier: Constants.cluster_layer_clustered, source: source)
        circlesLayer.circleRadius = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 16)
        circlesLayer.circleOpacity = NSExpression(forConstantValue: 1.0)
        circlesLayer.circleColor = NSExpression(forConstantValue: UIColor.clientMain)
        circlesLayer.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "cluster == YES")
        style.insertLayer(circlesLayer, at: self.biggestPossibleLayerIndex)
    }
```

Does someone know whats going on? Mapbox iOS sdk 6.3.0.

Comment: Could you provide the code of the Mapbox map configuration. I want to see how you configure clusterization.

Comment: @IvanovDeveloper i added the code of my cluster creation. In the map creation i don't do anything special. Just add the tap & doubletap gestures.